# C++ rand() not working with string array

Tags: c++, random

I'm creating a small program that allows the user to input 3 names (or whatever string they want). The program should then display all three strings (which is working), then it should use the `rand()` function to randomly display one of the three strings. This is the part that isn't functioning properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void display(string[], int);

const int SIZE = 3;

int main()
{
    string names[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << ": ";
        getline(cin, names[i]);
    }

    cout << endl;
    display(names, SIZE);

    int name = rand() % (2 + 1 - 0) + 0;
    cout << names[name];

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}

void display(string nm[], int n)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Name " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cout << nm[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

I had it set up differently before, and it gave me an error, but after changing it to what it is now, it always gives me the last element [2].

Is this a code error, or is it just that `rand()` always gives the same output on the same system?

Comment: `(2 + 1 - 0) + 0;` what?

Comment: use srand() and put time as sed. [Check this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/)

Comment: @manni66 the cppreference on rand() said this is how ranges are set up. I might have misunderstood this badly, but after reading the page 4 times that is what i got from that part. Basically the range should be from 0 - 2 to choose from 1 of the 3 elements

Comment: @Zharios instead? Did you read the linked page?

Comment: Do you think there happens some magic when you write `(2 + 1 - 0) + 0;` instead of `3;`?

Comment: @Zharios I don't entirely understand how to implement this into my code, are you suggesting i use `srand()` instead, or how the page suggests?

Comment: @manni66 as a beginner, C++ is really confusing on things such as this, and when the "official" c++ reference suggests doing this instead of a single integer, I assume that is correct, yes.

Comment: I don't know, on what cppreference **you** are looking, but [**mine**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) doesn't show such a crap. And it also states how to use srand.

Comment: @manni66 yeah, that's my confusion then, duly noted. Anyways, it's besides the point.

Comment: he dont need to include stdlib.h?

Comment: @Zharios it would be cstdlib in C++, but that may be included by iostream or string already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some discussion in the comments, it became apparent that the issue was that I was not [seeding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand) the `rand()` function. Below is part of the code that was not functioning, corrected.

(Also, as a sidenote, to use the `time()` function, `<ctime>` or `<time.h>` has to be included.)

```
srand(time(NULL));
int name = rand() % 3;
cout << names[name];
```

(Thanks to @manni66 for pointing out that it was useless to include an overly complicated calculation to get the range for `rand()`, as it just had to be a single integer.

Answer (score 1):

seeding with current time works :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

void display(string[], int);

const int SIZE = 3;

int main()
{
    string names[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << ": ";
        getline(cin, names[i]);
    }

    cout << endl;
    display(names, SIZE);

    srand(time(NULL)); // use current time as seed for random generator
    int name = rand() % 3 ;
    printf(" random %i \n", name);
    cout << names[name];

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}

void display(string nm[], int n)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Name " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cout << nm[i] << endl;
    }
}
```